# What are the differences between a leased line, and an ADSL/DSL link?

Tags: internet-connection, adsl

What the title states - What are the differences between a leased line, and an ADSL/DSL link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leased line usually has some Quality of Service level and a minimum repair time at least on any we have used. It may vary in different countries/regions

Comment: Could you elaborate on your experience please?

Comment: A leased line may guarantee 1.5Mbps synchronous. Speed could be anything but it is assured. ADSL is best effort with many factors impacting actual delivered speed.  Leased line will usually have a guarantee of repair time.  Sometimes 4 hours but it is spelled out.  ADSL is usually not so simple easy to get a repair.